# What's the meaning of the sentence "You are such a commitment"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I heard it from a vlog https://youtu.be/tWZl11CYPNM?t=140.
Looked up on google but still not clear about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if it could be this meaning:
[Merriam-Webster *commitment*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commitment)

> 1 c  : the state or an instance of being obligated or emotionally impelled
> *a commitment to a cause *

So, having agreed to do the filming they are doing, one of them is jokingly complaining that it is turning out to be more trouble than they expected. But, they continue because they have promised and are obligated - committed.

Comment: Thanks. That makes much more sense to me now.